# Tinymce in angular2

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'am trying to integrate tinymce with my angular2 app.
I followed these steps: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/ and also this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IXelrVEoWI and the corresponding code from github: https://github.com/tabvn/angular-blog

I have installed the npm package and created the files.
I didn't have a typings.d.ts file, so i created one and put

declare var tinymce: any;

in it.

I suspect thats where the error is, but i'am not sure.

I have created the editor component:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, EventEmitter, Input, Output, OnInit, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {isNullOrUndefined} from "util";


@Component({
    selector: 'text-editor',
    templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {


    @Input() elementId: string;
    @Input() value: any = "";
    @Output() onEditorKeyup: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    baseURL: string = '/';

    constructor() {
    }


    ngOnInit() {


    }


    editor;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#' + this.elementId,
            plugins: ['link', 'paste', 'table'],
            skin_url: this.baseURL + 'assets/skins/lightgray',
            setup: editor => {
                this.editor = editor;
                editor.on('keyup', () => {
                    const content = editor.getContent();
                    this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
                });
            },
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        tinymce.remove(this.editor);
    }


    didSetValue: boolean = false;


    ngOnChanges(){

        console.log(this.value);

        if(!isNullOrUndefined(this.editor) && this.value !== "" && !this.didSetValue){

            console.log(this.value);
            this.didSetValue = true;
            this.editor.setContent(this.value);


        }
    }

}
```

and used it here:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-10">
  <label for="description">Description:</label>
  <text-editor [value]="defaultBodyValue" [elementId]="'description'" (onEditorKeyup)="onBodyTextEditorKeyUp($event)"></text-editor>
</div>
```

UPDATED:

Found out that I was missing the include in my module, not in the component.
Now this block of code:

```
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
```

Throws this error:

GET http://192.168.4.13:3007/util 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:1382ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:245Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:171(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1405send @ VM1084:3fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1781ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:518(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:1780leadingCommentAndMetaRegEx @ system.src.js:2809load.metadata.deps @ system.src.js:3387loader @ system.src.js:3701loader @ system.src.js:4093loader @ system.src.js:4556constructor.meta @ system.src.js:4825(anonymous function) @ system.src.js:407ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:232Zone.run @ zone.js:114(anonymous function) @ zone.js:502ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:401cancelFn.invoke @ zone.js:339
(index):20 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://192.168.4.13:3007/util(…)

I don't have any routes for /util, so i'am unsure what its trying to load and from where...

Comment: could you update with NgModule and Component where you use the text-editor. I had make the integrate and works fine for me.

Comment: You need to include the library in your *module*, not your component.

Comment: I've updated it with the complete code for the component that tries to use the editor component.

Comment: I've updated the code above to reflect the change to include the editor in the module, and not the component. It now throws a new error.

Comment: jonrsharpe could you update with an answer that I can mark as the right one. Based on your answer regarding moving the include from the component to the module, I was able to fix the issue eventually.